# Kibana Dark Theme Not Loading?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, elastic-stack

have a kibana dashboard and system loaded up and password protected.
It would appear that even though the URL preferences a dark theme, it automatically loads to the light theme?

No pun intended, can you shed some light onto this and perhaps share a solution?

Comment: What version of Kibana are you using? 4.1, 4.2 or 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Solved (sort of). In short, it is a verified bug at this point. You can read more about it here.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-dark-theme-to-load/40434/7